# OnActivtyResult for createDeleteRequest() on Android 11

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

Unfortunately, Android 11 changes its way to manage storage permissions.

I wanted to do delete and rename functions and modified my code as follows:

```
        private void deleteFile(int p, View view){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Supprimer ?").setMessage(videoFolder.get(p).getTitle()).setNegativeButton("Annuler", (dialog, which) -> {
    
                }).setPositiveButton("Oui", (dialog, which) -> {
                    ArrayList<Uri> fichiers = new ArrayList<>();
                    Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(videoFolder.get(p).getId()));
                    File file = new File(videoFolder.get(p).getPath());
    
    
                    fichiers.add(contentUri);
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        PendingIntent demande = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(context.getContentResolver(), fichiers);
                        try {
                            ((Activity) context).startIntentSenderForResult(demande.getIntentSender(),1,new Intent(), 0,0,0);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    
                    }else {
    
    
                    boolean deleted = file.delete();
                        if (deleted){
                            context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(contentUri, null, null);
                            videoFolder.remove(p);
                            notifyItemRemoved(p);
                            notifyItemRangeChanged(p,videoFolder.size());
                            Snackbar.make(view, "Fichier supprimé avec succès", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                        }else{
                            Snackbar.make(view, "Erreur, le fichier n'a pas été supprimé", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
    }
                }).show();
            }
```

But i don't know how to get `onActivityResult` in order to make what `file.delete()` did.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: What has contentUri to do with file?

Comment: @blackapps i din't understand your comment

Comment: Wel i do not understand what your variables contentUri and file have to do with each other.

Comment: @blackapps file is when you aren't forced to use the new system of permission and uri is when you must use createDeleteRequest that requires a uri type

Comment: Then separate in two code blocks as you mix it up now which is quite confusing.

Comment: @blackapps i don't see what you want me to do, however, I can't get OnActivityResult, i don't know how to implement it

Comment: And i still dont see what your File instance has to do with that Uri. You did not even try to explain. And a file.delete() has nothing to do with an onActivityResult so i understand nothing.

Comment: @blackapps At start, there wasn't the Uri. The File was to execute file.delete() because it was the easiest way. But since android 11, we can't do that anymore. So I tried to use createDeleteRequest that requires an Uri so I add the file to and Uri in order to create the request and I kept the file.delete is this android 10 or less

Comment: @blackapps and now I want to implement an onactivityresult of the pending intent in case android 11 is used because i startIntentSenderForResult but i don't know how to get the result

Comment: Of course you can use file.delete() under Android 11 too. Tell why you cant.

Comment: Further i can not see that file.delete() would be for the same file as your delete request. Please adapt your code to make that clear. Make clear what your file instance has to do with that uri. I asked that already 23 hours ago. We cannot follow you now.

Comment: Further you can just implement an onActivityResult in the usual way and see if it gets triggered.

Comment: @blackapps No you can't use it, it doesn't work. Oh ! I just saw that there's a "else" that was removed by error, plaese see the edit. If the version is android 11+, i use the createdeleterequest, if not i use .delete(). Too I d'ont know how to implement OnCativityresult, that's the point

Comment: Just make an empty onActivityResult with a toast in it. See if it gets triggered.

Comment: I added `@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(this, "L'activité est finie", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`   and it made nothing

Comment: @blackapps we can go chat if it's better

Comment: `new Intent()` ??? Should not that be `demande` ?