# How to use OnActivityResult with startIntentSenderForResult in Adpater

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, onactivityresult

For my app, I want to create a delete function and since Android 11 we must create a pending intent etc...

I  created my Intent and the windows displays but now I wanna use the ActivityResult but I don't know how. My function is in my Adpater:

```
private void deleteFile(int p, View view){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Supprimer ?").setMessage(videoFolder.get(p).getTitle()).setNegativeButton("Annuler", (dialog, which) -> {

            }).setPositiveButton("Oui", (dialog, which) -> {
                ArrayList<Uri> fichiers = new ArrayList<>();
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(videoFolder.get(p).getId()));
                File file = new File(videoFolder.get(p).getPath());


                fichiers.add(contentUri);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                        PendingIntent demande = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(context.getContentResolver(), fichiers);
                                        
                    try {
                        ((Activity) context).startIntentSenderForResult(demande.getIntentSender(),123,new Intent(), 0,0,0);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }else{

                    boolean deleted = file.delete();
                    if (deleted){
                        context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(contentUri, null, null);
                        videoFolder.remove(p);
                        notifyItemRemoved(p);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(p,videoFolder.size());
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Fichier supprimé avec succès", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Erreur, le fichier n'a pas été supprimé", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }).show();
        }

And I tried to add this in my MainActivity class :

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

But it doesn't work...
I'm lost, if someone can help me !

[image: My code organisation]

My code : https://textup.fr/570657Bd

Thanks

Comment: You still dont tell why you dont use file.delete(). You still didnt tell full path of file. And you could have referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68527747/onactivtyresult-for-createdeleterequest-on-android-11

Comment: `But it doesn't work...` If you mean that onActivityResult does not get triggered then better say so.

Comment: Tell full path. Nobody knows the value of `videoFolder.get(p).getPath()`. Imagine!

Comment: @blackapps Like i said in the other post, you can't use file.delete() since android 11. My app works well with file delete for android 10 and lower but not for android 11

Comment: @blackapps yes, the onCativityresult isn't trigered

Comment: @blackapps idon't understand tell full path. Check the edit, i will post my entire code

Comment: That does not help. `new File(videoFolder.get(p).getPath())`. new File() needs a full path. Tell which path you use. Tell the value of `videoFolder.get(p).getPath()`.

Comment: videoFolder is a folder on your development pc. It is not a folder on your Android device. It is still unclear to me wich file you wanna delete.

Comment: videoFolder isn't a folder on my pc, it's an arraylist of videoModel

Comment: `Like i said in the other post, you can't use file.delete() since android 11` Well you are wrong. Its still usable. I also told you that in that other post. Strange you still dont tell which file exactly. Where does the file reside on your Android device? Full path please.

Comment: I wanna delete a video the user has chosen, that's why I use getpath

Comment: Just tell the result. Tell the value you use in new File (...). And if it is Uri.getPath() then you cannot use it for the File class. Now please finally tell the value. What does getPath() return?

Comment: Further if you let the user choose a file you will get an uri. Use that uri to delete that file. Using Uri.getPath() makes no sense.

Comment: "/storage/emulated/0/Vidéos carrées 5G/jeux-video-5g-orange.mp4" with a systm.out.println(videoFolder.get(p).getPath()

Comment: Ok. Finally full path. Thanks. And this is on an Android 11 device? Then who created the `Vidéos carrées 5G` folder? And how?

Comment: That' me on my test phone, I added the folder by a pc

Comment: You should of course have told that at the start of your post. Ok. Next: if you let the user select files you will normally get uries. How is it possible you have a classic file system path?

Comment: I don't know. I managed to do something. I created an Interface for deletefiles and it works. But I don't know how to do the same for rename

Comment: @blackapps i created an interface but i do'nt know how to get on ActivityResult

Comment: @blackapps for my rename function i did an interface etc like i did before, I used Files.move() but i got an error "Operation not permitted". what am i supposed to do ?

Comment: I dont see interfaces and i dont see code and you did not answer my questions.

Comment: @blackapps I did, i said "I don't know"